# How can I make in Android more activities from a list?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna import data from Firebase to a list(2-4 list items). If you click on a list you go to another list(this list has around 10-15 list items).

After you click on that list you go to another "activity" that will have some data and some buttons.

Here is an example:

```
 - School 1
 - School 2
 - School 3
```

If you click on the first list will appear something like this.

```
 - Class 1
 - Class 2
 - Class 3
 - Class 4
 - Class 5
 - Class 6
 - Class 7
.
.
.
```

And if you click on Class 4, for example, you will get a page like this:

```
 - 24 students
 - 10 girls
 - 14 boys
 - Name of the homeroom teacher
```

I am a newbie in Android and programming with Java so I would appreciate if you would give me some help. I am thinking using intents but I am not sure if I can do that in this case.

Comment: are you able to get firebase data in your app?

Comment: @PeterMushirih yes I can do that. I know how to import a list, post with a button data to firebase data and things like that

Comment: you can then use a switch statement to choose what list to send to new intent,then send the list to new intent using the PUT action of intent

Comment: I will try this and see if it works ok.

Comment: Also, check out the Recycler View that comes with the FirebaseUI. Pretty useful when you have a list and handle events effectively.